# How to determine which element triggered accordion collapsed event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have an accordion that I fill dynamically using JQuery.
I would like to start a script specific to each element on trigger.
I figured easily out how to check for a collapse :

```
<script>
  $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
       alert($(this).text());
});
</script>
```

However, in $(this), I have all the accordion and not only the element that collapsed. I can't check for a specific ID as I don't know it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the Event Object thru the callback and use **[`e.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)** instead of `this`. I replaced the `alarm()` with `console.log()` so look at the left hand corner and you'll see each `.collapse` report its `#id` on `show.bs.collapse` event.

### Demo

```js
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.id);
});
```

```css
.collapse::before {
  content: attr(id)
}

.collapse {
  font-size: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 3px ridge blue;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-left: 70%
}
```

```html
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<div class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col0">COL0</div>

<div class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col1">COL1</div>

<div class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#col2">COL2</div>
<hr>
<div id='col0' class="collapse panel-collapse">
  <div class='panel-body'></div>
</div>

<div id='col1' class="collapse panel-collapse">
  <div class='panel-body'></div>
</div>

<div id='col2' class="collapse panel-collapse">
  <div class='panel-body'></div>
</div>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot awesome answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 'this' but rather use the 'event' parameter from the function like this:

```
<script>
    $('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function (event) { // Note the 'event' parameter

        // event.target is the collapsed element
        alert(event.target);

        // You can use this element to get the id like this: $(event.target).attr('id')
    });
</script>
```